# Running multiple concurrent Python programs accessing the same database table

Tags: python, concurrency

Is there anything in Python that allows you to run multiple concurrent Python programs that could potentially access the same database table and to prevent each program from using the full cpu and thereby allow the server to have some additional capacity left over?

Comment: What database software you'll use?

Comment: Postgresql would be my choice of database

Comment: Well try it and you'll see, databases are created for concurrent reading and writing so I don't think you'll have any problems. Sleep between queries can balance you CPU load.

Comment: These would be adhoc programs submitted by users who would not have sleep in their programs. Need some way to spawn programs and limit their cpu usage.

Comment: This is what I'll do, first I'll try it without any fancy algorithms, maybe the database will manage and if it doesn't I'll do some sort of Query Queue or migrate to another database or buy more machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

1. multiple concurrent Python programs - see http://wiki.python.org/moin/Concurrency, for the start I would try with builtin module multiprocessing (http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)
2. access the same database table - each process should create own db connection - after that concurrency is managed by/or configured within rdbms and/or connection/query options. If you really need to sync between processes - using Locks/Semaphores could help.
3. prevent each program from using the full cpu - it depends what your processes should do, I would go with:

   - having one main program that runs all the time (master process), does pauses (time.sleep, gevent.sleep or similar) and spawns and controls spawned processes (workers)
   - spawned processes do the job (workers) - open new connection, do db actions and quit

I'm sure that some of the workflows/systems provided by multiprocessing (or other) modules could fit your needs (Workers, Pools, Queues, Pipes, Shared states, Synchronization, ...).

Comment: Thanks, will have a long look.