# how to get unique data from pydev to postgres

Tags: python, sql, eclipse, postgresql, pydev

I got two codes and they work separately but I am unsure about how to integrate them together. I want to get the unique referee names from pydev using eclipse to postgresql using pgadmin4. Thank you very much for your help.

Code 1:
    #!/usr/bin/python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
import psycopg2
import sys
import csv
from itertools import count
path = r'C:\Users\sammy\Downloads\E0.csv'
with open(path, "r") as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    firstline = 1
    con = None
    con = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='football' user='postgres' password='XXX'")   
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE Referees")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Referees (RefereeID VARCHAR, RefereeName VARCHAR)")

    try:
        for row in readCSV:
            if firstline:
                firstline=0
                continue 
            RefereeID = row[10]
            RefereeName = row[10]
            data = (RefereeID, RefereeName)
            query = "INSERT INTO Referees (RefereeID, RefereeName) VALUES (%s, %s);"
            print (RefereeID)
            print (RefereeName)
            cursor = con.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query, data)
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
        if con:
            con.rollback() 
            print ("Error %s % e", e)
            sys.exit(1) 
    finally:
        if con:
            con.commit()
            con.close()

print(" ".join(row))
out=open("new_data.csv", "w")
output = csv.writer(out)

for row in data:
    output.writerow(row)

out.close()
```

Code 2:
    import csv

```
path = r'C:\Users\sammy\Downloads\E0.csv'
with open(path, "r") as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

    refereename= []

    class Teams:
         for row in readCSV:
            referee= row[10]
            refereename.append(referee)

        for x in refereename:
            if x not in uniquerefereename:
                uniquerefereename.append(x)

 print (refereename)
print (uniquerefereename)

 refereesorted= sorted(uniquerefereename)

 print (refereesorted)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470004/running-multiple-concurrent-python-programs-accessing-the-same-database-table

Comment: Nop, not the answer to my question

Comment: i need some help to directly edit the code please..